# clockreport, total productivity by day?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

With clock reports, one can set `:step day`, and then I have a list of totals by day.
Like:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :tstart "<-1w>" :tend "<+1d>" :step day :scope ("dev.org" "tst.org") :maxlevel 1 :narrow 65
| File      | Headline                                                          | Time   |
|-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+--------|
|           | ALL *Total time*                                                  | *6:38* |
|-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+--------|
| dev.org   | *File time*                                                       | *3:04* |
| tst.org   | *File time*                                                       | *3:34* |
```

But it's quite verbose, lots of info. I'd like a summary.

I'd like to post-process that list so that I have the total productivity by day, like:

```
[2015-02-19 Thu] 6:38  (Dev.org 3:00, testing.org 3:20)  
[2015-02-20 Fri] 5:03  (Dev.org 3:00, testing.org 2:03)  
[2015-02-21 Sat] 4:30  (Dev.org 2:00, testing.org 2:30)
```

I'm willing to write some code to maybe grep out the relevant bits and glue it all together.

But I'm kinda wondering, how do I go about starting something like this? I.e, what would be the building blocks?

Can I use like the :formatter property with some function? or can I use bable to post-process this with some bash/grep/awk/sed/cut, or with python?

**[edit]**  A bash solution.. 
So far I've hacked myself something together with bash.

I generate a report as above. Then export it into ascii into report.txt. Then I use a bash script:

```
cat ~/git/LeoUfimtsev.github.io/org/reports.txt | egrep 'Daily|Total' | tr -d '[[:space:]]' | sed 's/Daily/\nDaily/g' | sed 's/\*Totaltime\*\*/ /g' | sed 's/Dailyreport://g' | sed 's/ALL/ /g' | sed -E -e 's/Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|\*//g'
```

And then I get something like this:

```
  37:47
2015-02-19  6:42
2015-02-20  4:02
2015-02-21  0:00
2015-02-22  2:55
2015-02-23  4:09
2015-02-24  4:37
```

Now I just have to automate things.

- open report.org buffer
- export to ascii
- run bash script
- show output somewhere
- Plot onto chart :-D

I think these are probably straight-forward enough for me to tacke on my own thou. That said, if anyone has any better advice, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the sub-question: *Can I use like the :formatter property with some function? or can I use bable to post-process this with some bash/grep/awk/sed/cut, or with python?*

You can post-process a `clocktable` by naming it and then referencing it using babel:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :properties ("CLOCK") :header "#+NAME: clocked\n"
#+NAME: clocked

#+END:

#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var clocked=clocked :results table
(cl-loop for row in (subseq clocked 4) ; skip headers
         collect (list (org-parse-time-string (nth 0 row))
                       (org-duration-string-to-minutes (nth 2 row))))
#+end_src

#+NAME: clocked-b
#+RESULTS:
| (0 48 23 26 2 2015 nil nil nil) | 19 |
| (0 42 23 26 2 2015 nil nil nil) |  6 |
| (0 9 22 26 2 2015 nil nil nil)  |  3 |
| (0 6 22 26 2 2015 nil nil nil)  |  2 |
| (0 2 22 26 2 2015 nil nil nil)  |  4 |
| (0 55 21 26 2 2015 nil nil nil) |  7 |
| (0 41 21 26 2 2015 nil nil nil) | 13 |
```

You'll need to figure out the aggregating...